# UITextView : Text starts from 2nd line of text view

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a strange problem. I have 3 `UITextField`s and one `UITextView`. I can move from one `UITextField`to next `UITextField` by:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
    //-- try to find next responde
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];

    if (nextResponder) 
    {
        //-- found next responce ,so set it
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
        //-- not found remove keyboard
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }   

    return YES;
}
```

Its all works fine until it comes to `UITexView`, then my cursor moves at 2nd line of the text view in place of 1st line of text view.

Text view is taken from IB.

The code for text view:

```
- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    optionalText.hidden = YES ;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textView.center.y-100) animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{       
    // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        // Be sure to test for equality using the "isEqualToString" message
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added      
        if ([[commentTxtView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
        {
            optionalText.hidden = NO ;
            NSLog(@"Text View is null");
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What could be the problem? Why does it not start from 1st line of text view?

Comment: what is a scrollview in this case? I'd double check this line: [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textView.center.y-100) animated:YES];

Comment: Can you show us where you call your textFieldShouldReturn method ? If you call it like in the very beginning of the view life cycle, since you have more than one textField, the condition "if (nextResponder)" will automatically send you to the next textField.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I bet your `textFieldShouldReturn:` should return `NO` in case the `nextResponder` is your `UITextField`. Right now you are always returning `YES`, which means that the key probably being passed to the `UITextView`, which will then insert the new line.

Comment: so How can I solve it ? Actually I solved it by just putting [textView becomeFirstResponder]; in textFieldShouldReturn method when nextResponder is not available. I know it just matter of sequences as I know when my text view is the last one.

Answer (score 3):

For Anybody coming in looking for Swift 2.0 translation...

Instead of returning `true` in `textFieldShouldReturn` after `yourUIITextView.becomeFirstResponder()`, return `false`.