# get into a second line in uitextview, UITextView, ios

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview, uitextfielddelegate, uitextviewdelegate

My view is containing :

```
first name ( UITextField )
last name  ( UITextField )
email      ( UITextField )
note       ( UITextView )
```

picture is following
[image]

The codes below is used to handle when you enter a return key

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {    // invoked when user hits return of keyboard from a text field
    if ( textField      ==  self.firstName)
        [self.lastName becomeFirstResponder];
    else if (textField  == self.lastName)
        [self.email becomeFirstResponder];
    else if (textField  == self.email) {
        [self.note becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;

}
```

When I am at `email` field and hit `next`, I am landing at `note` but at the second line like following ( the light blue cursor is at a second line )
[image]

I dont get it. Should the cursor be at the first line of the `note` .

Any idea about this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

I am still not sure whether the following peace of code works for you(sorry for that)...but give a try...

By Changing the curson location:

```
notetextView.editable = YES;
notetextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 0);//i have put in as 2,you can change the location based on your requirent.
```

Your issue looks strange,and have upvoted your question,so that others can answer,if the above code won't work you...

Comment: i put (0,0) but cursor is still placing at the second line

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TK4JF2Dk have tried roughly for you..i haven't faced any issues like your facing now...check for position of email texftfield and note textview whether its overlapping...

Comment: you created the textview in the IBOutlet?..if not then remove the line  called notetextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);

Comment: anyways thanks for your help, solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037679/uitextview-text-starts-from-2nd-line-of-text-view)

Answer (score 3):

write return NO when email text is return.
Try this code.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {    // invoked when user hits return of keyboard from a text field
    if ( textField      ==  self.firstName)
        [self.lastName becomeFirstResponder];
    else if (textField  == self.lastName)
        [self.email becomeFirstResponder];
    else if (textField  == self.email) {
        [self.note becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO; 
    }

    return YES;
}
```